# ValidationError: ["'02/12/2020' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i have a form that takes in a date and class_id.
when the user posts the data i want to use the date to query my models for any instance with the same date.. but i end up getting this error code

```
ValidationError: ["'02/12/2020' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

this is my views.py:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
      class_name = get_object_or_404(ClassRoom, pk=request.POST['class_name'])  # class name
      attendance_date = request.POST['date_field']  # date

    # get the students in the class which is current active

    # check if the student is current active

      students_attendance = StudentAttendance.objects.filter(attendance_date=attendance_date)
```

and my models.py implementation is:

```
class StudentAttendance(models.Model):

  student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student_attendance')
  attendance_date = models.DateField()
  status = models.ForeignKey(AttendanceStatus, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  notes = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
  private_notes = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
  #signed_by = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    unique_together = (("student", "attendance_date", 'status'),)
    ordering = ('-attendance_date', 'student',)
```

any suggestion on how to solve this bug...

**NB**:
    1. i changed my settings.py to localize the time like this

```
from  django.conf.locale.en import formats as en_formart

en_formart.DATE_FORMAT = ('%d %m %y', )
en_formart.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%m/%d/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%y', '%b %d %Y',
                    '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y',
                    '%B %d, %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y','%b. %d, %Y')
DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/ Y'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'GMT'

#USE_I18N = True

#USE_L10N = False
```

nothing worked i still get the same error...Please help A Brother

Comment: The formatting system is disabled by default. To enable it, it’s necessary to set **`USE_L10N = True`** in your settings file.

Comment: but i still get the same error message after updating my setting.py

Answer (score 0):

what i came up with was to change the date format on jquery Datepicker so my post request word be formated correctly

```
$( function() {
    $( ".dateinput" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
```